# replacing elements between two lists using prolog

Tags: list, prolog

My task is to make `myReplace(E1,L1,E2,L2)` such that the very first occurrence of `E1` in `L1` gets replaced by `E2` and is returned in `L2`. I have written the below described code and it is working properly.

```
myReplace(E1,[],E2,[]).
myReplace(E1,[E1|Xs],E2,[E2|Ys]):-
  myReplace(E1,Xs,E1,Ys).
myReplace(E1,[H|Hs],E2,[H|Ts]):-
  E1 \= H,
  myReplace(E1,Hs,E2,Ts).
```

However, For example `myReplace(2,[1,2,3,2,1],5,X)` should give `X = [1,5,3,2,1]` and `X = [1,2,3,5,1]`. But my code is only giving one solution which is `X = [1,5,3,2,1]`.

Similarly, when `myReplace(2,X,5,[1,5,3,5,1])` should backtrack over the solutions `X = [1,2,3,5,1]` and `X = [1,5,3,2,1]` only, but my solution gives me one more solution as `X = [1,5,3,5,1]`.

Could you please help me resolve this.

Thank you :)

Comment: If `myReplace/4` is to replace the *very first occurrence* as you say in your definition, why is `X = [1,2,3,5,1]` a valid solution to `myReplace(2,[1,2,3,2,1],5,X)`, when it is *not* the first occurrence? Perhaps it should be, "replace *one* occurrence", not *first* occurrence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
myReplace(E1,[E1|Xs],E2,[E2|Xs]).

myReplace(E1,[H|Hs],E2,[H|Ts]):-
  myReplace(E1,Hs,E2,Ts).
```

?

If I'm not wrong, this impose one (and only one) replacement.

Take in count that you have to delete

```
myReplace(E1,[],E2,[]).
```

otherwise you get `L1 = L2` (no replacement) as a solution.

And observe that, as pointed by Lurker, this isn't "the **very first occurrence** of E1 in L1 gets replaced".

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you want to get all answers from substituting each one occurrence of E1 in L1. You can get the backtracking for free if you use `append/3` for this:

```
my_replace(X, As, Y, Bs) :-
    append(As_front, [X|As_back], As),
    append(As_front, [Y|As_back], Bs).
```

With this definition I get:

```
?- my_replace(2,[1,2,3,2,1],5,X).
X = [1, 5, 3, 2, 1] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, 5, 1] ;
false
```

See the [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39645786/1812457) to see how to see what the problem with your original code was.

Comment: The above predicate is not reversible due to append it give some solutions and falls into infinite loop after that .

Comment: @coder You can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39673366/1812457) for a solution that works correctly in the most general case.